# MVC view escape @ in image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the name of the picture in Model.PictureName. However I need to add .jpg to it.
This gives an error every time. I already tried the escape charackters in other topics, they don't seem to work for this.
The framework is MVC4 Razor

```
<img src="~/Images/@Model.PictureName.jpg" />
```

Comment: `mvc` ? Which framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like ASP.NET Razor syntax. Try enclosing the expression in parentheses:

```
<img src="~/Images/@(Model.PictureName).jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Feeling ashamed for asking such an easy thing :p

Comment: No need to feel ashamed, it's a common headache for those who haven't encountered the situation before. As a general rule, only use the plain `@` prefix when your value has whitespace around it. If it's embedded in text use `@()`. Razor just needs a little help determining what is the actual variable name it needs to replace, in those scenarios.